# Adjust Resize causing progressbar to shift to the right

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-relativelayout

I have a progress bar inside a RelativeLayout. Everything works fine until I display a softkeyboard and the progressbar shifts to the right.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_video_video_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".33"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_video_video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/video_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

How do I prevent the progressBar from shifting to the right?

**Edit1: _______________Entire Layout___________________________**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/blackBackground">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_video_video_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".33"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_video_video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/video_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_video_textview_chat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Chat"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_video_video_layout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/whiteText"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_video_sendmessage_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/whiteText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/fragment_video_video_divider1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:background="@color/dividerColor"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fragment_video_sendmessage_edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Say something in chat"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment_video_sendmessage_button"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_video_video_divider1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fragment_video_sendmessage_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="Send"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_video_video_divider1"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_video_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_video_textview_chat"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fragment_video_sendmessage_layout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/whiteText">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit2:____________________________________________**

Tried changing progressbar to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

This fixes the shifting progressbar however it causes the videoview to shift

[image]

Comment: try changing ProgressBar `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Comment: That ends up shifting my entire videoview to the left, but it stops the progressbar from shifting

Comment: can you send your full xml layout maybe other factors affect the display, like how did you display the layout when your relative layout height is 0dp `android:layout_height="0dp"`, maybe im missing something here

Comment: sure, I added the layout in the edit above

Comment: I tried your code in my phone the only problem I encounter is that the height of the video shrink when accessing the keypad. but it work betters when I change the relative layout height 0dp to `250dp`

Comment: Hey thanks for trying. But I need it to be dynamic using .33 so that it covers 1/3 of screen for all devices

Comment: I don't know why it shifts my videoview to the left, makes no sense. I added another edit above

Comment: lol you just need to add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in VideoView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when I add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in VideoView.

```
<VideoView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_video_video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

Comment: Haha didn't think of that because it was working without it until I changed the progressbar xD Thanks a bunch mate appreciate it